# Who owns the intellectual property to Fragile Allegiance?

Tags: legal, copyright

Fragile Allegiance was developed by Gremlin Interactive, which was later acquired by Infogrames (Atari). I couldn't find any details of the acquisition though.

The only interesting thing I have found online is that the owner of the registered trademark Fragile Allegiance is Interplay, who published Fragile Allegiance. However, the only copyright note I've found was in one installation .ini file, claiming it for Gremlin.

<del>What are the common business practices when it comes to old, unused IPs? What do publishers/developers actually need to legally claim an intellectual property? Does anyone have an experience with contacting big publishers with copyright/IP inquiries?</del>

[Related legal question.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.atari.com/publish would be where to contact Atari (sorry, you do need to login using an Atari account).

Comment: The link lead to form for those interested in "getting your game published or distributed", but thanks anyway, I tried to contact Atari; even when these types of requests never get a reply from my experience.

Comment: I don't actually know where that goes, but I doubt it is anyone in our office so I don't think I can nag in person about it :-/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I guess I'll have to pester the original Gremlin people.