# Copyright of some arcade classics

Tags: legal, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How closely can a game resemble another game without legal problems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems)

So suppose I'm currently developing a variant of a snakes game for the iPhone, and you decided to call it "snakes".

First, in general, how would you find out if a name's been copyrighted or not? It's probably safe with "snakes" because it's such a common word, and that there's been so many games around (**please** correct me if I'm wrong), but with some people copyrighting the name "edge", it would be best to be a bit careful.

Second, suppose I decided to go with some name that is guaranteed to be different (e.g EL SERPENTES DE LOS REYES), would gameplay be a point of contention on copyright issues? For example, the tetris game is sort of "copyrighted" at the apple app store, and there was a crackdown on anyone using the word "tris" or anything related to it. However, if there was a game with the gameplay of tetris (or loosely **very** similar), with the name "BLOXODEREX", can it be liable to copyright/DMCA issues?

Comment: Names are trademarked. Tetris, and its related terms are trademarks, and that is the usual grounds for their takedowns.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: You can look up trademarks registred in the US on the website of the [US Patent and Trademark office](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4006:4t4900.1.1) - but note that when you distribute your game internationally, you might violate trademarks which are registred in other countries.