# Implementing an existing (but out of print) game electronically

Tags: legal

One of my favorite games is the old Avalon Hill class, [PanzerBlitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PanzerBlitz).

I would like to implement it electronically, and have a couple questions related to that:

1. Would I be in *legal* trouble if I do this? (note - this is not for sale or distribution)
2. How would I go about implementing the hex grid and piece database most effectively (each piece has a variety of 'factors' (movement, carryability, attack, defense, unit type)?

The game play and mechanics are already well-defined in the written rules - so I'm *not* writing the game from scratch - just programming it to follow the board game.

Comment: These two questions are on completely different topics, so should be separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

For question 1, see [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems)

For question 2, you might find some past questions tagged with Hexagon useful.  It's not clear whether you have referenced them yet.  See https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=hexagon

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can make a similar game, do not use the name, their assets(images++) or copy anything else directly without their approval.