# License for a Breakout

Tags: android, ios, copyright, licensing, appstore

This may not be an appropriate question for gamedev.stackexchange.com.

I'd like to make a basic [Breakout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_%28video_game%29) game with Unity.
I'd also like to sell it on the Mac App Store, iOS App Store, Google's Play Store, Windows 8 Store etc.

I'm not sure however if that will cause trouble with Copyright.
I asked Google but I didn't find any helpful results.

Can I use the game-concept without buying a license?

I know that there are plenty of games with the same concept on various platforms, I just want to be certain.

Comment: Asking people on the internet for legal advice is usually not a great idea, even if it may be correct. The best advice comes from a lawyer. However, this article makes a compelling argument http://toucharcade.com/2008/09/18/ataris-legal-team-attacking-iphone-breakout-clones/

Comment: @Evan Thanks for the link, it helps!
I don't want to get in trouble, I think I'll rather let it be.

Comment: @NSAddict Does this answer your question? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems

Comment: @Byte56 Yes, this was helpful as well! Thanks

Comment: The trick is to avoid trademarked names.  Gameplay is very very difficult to protect.