# Can I use the graphics or music of an abandoned game in my game?

Tags: graphics, music, licensing

I was wondering that if a game has been officially closed by the owner can I use their graphics or music they used in their game?

Comment: I don't have a degree in law, so I will post my opinion as a comment: 
Even though they officially closed that game, they could still want to use the artwork they created - and more importantly, have copyright to - in something else. If I park my car somewhere and state that I will never drive it again, it's still my car. You're not allowed to take parts you need for your own.

Comment: and if the game is created on the same historic story with different story line. does that comes in the copyright?

Comment: @Peethor one more thing the game i am talking about is "Lord Of Ultima" from EA but i have searched on the internet and failed to find the license of the product. In this case can i use the graphics?

Comment: @DeveloperNation I would appreciate it if you looked into this sort of thing before you came here. Information about how the legal system works in any country is available online in many places. Don't use art from other games **UNLESS YOU HAVE EXPRESS WRITEN CONSENT!** ;)

Comment: Perhaps you should come up with your own ideas and media? Or find someone artistic to make a game with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not.

Just because a piece of media is no longer used commercially does not mean that its copyright is void. Even when the company which originally held the copyright does no longer exist, their assets are not safe to use because as part of the liquidation of the company those rights might have gotten transferred to some other company.

Comment: one more thing the game i am talking about is "Lord Of Ultima" from EA but i have searched on the internet and failed to find the license of the product. In this case can i use the graphics?

Comment: EA probably still holds the liscence so you have to ask them for permission, be prepared to offer some money.

Comment: nope i cant see a licence of "Lord Of Ultima" if you can please post me the link.

Comment: @DeveloperNation When you find no license terms, "all rights reserved" applies. Licenses don't remove your rights, they give you rights you hadn't had in the first place. No license, no rights. When the copyright holder is Electronic Arts Inc, you better be careful because their legal department is known to be quite ruthless.

Comment: @Philipp thanks a lot for your advice just one last thing a game called "Crown Of The Gods" which is identical copy of Lord Of Ultima (graphics have been created by them but story and other things have been copied by them). How come they are building a game that is identical and have "all rights reserved" without getting permission from EA.

Comment: @DeveloperNation This is addressed in the question ["How closely can a game legally resemble another?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another). Also, just because someone does it doesn't mean it is legal.