# Can I use the idea of grappling hook and wingsuit from just cause 3 and use it in my game?

Tags: copyright

I really liked the idea of grappling hook and wingsuit, and I am inspired by it.And I have already created the model,texture,animation,script which are required for it by myself.So,my simple question is that can I use it in my game?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another)

Answer (score 1):

Grapling hooks have been used before just cause 3. Think of the legend of zelda series. Wingsuits have been used in ssx, and are quite similar to the delta hanger in far cry.

This is like asking 'can I use cars in my game or will rockstar, the maker of gta, sue me?'. Yes, you can use them. Just make everything yourself. Don't use anyone elses models, textures or code or any other property without their approval.

Ideas are not property.

Fyi: I'm not a lawyer. Technically, anyone can sue you for pretty much anything. Even if you win, going to court is expensive.

Comment: Expanding on this, while certain intellectual property is legally recognized (copyrights, trademarks, patents), game mechanics are not typically things we can attach these rights to. However, if you copy a whole game so closely that a player might reasonably confuse your product for a product by the original creators, then they have a more clear-cut case against your game. (Probably not an issue in this case). Like Peethor, I am not a lawyer, just relaying info I've picked up which should not be taken as legal advice.