# Copyright of concept?

Tags: legal, copyright

There is a game that I really like to play when I was young. But there are some features that are not implemented that would be cool.

How can I find copyright database from games editor ?

Comment: Asking about similarity & copyright is a duplicate, so I removed that part. The remainder of your question might not be a dupe, but it's also a bit unclear. What exactly do you mean by "find copyright database from games editor"? Are you asking about how to look up the copyright information about an existing game/editor?

Comment: OK, for example, how can I check if Im allowed to use a specific feature from a game.

Comment: I don't believe that part of the question is substantially different enough from [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another) to be reasked. If you disagree, or don't understand why, you can ask about it on [meta](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes its fine. Im going to read your suggested post. Thanks