# How to know if a game concept is "different enough"?

Tags: game-design

For the past year or so, I've been designing a top-down zombie shooter game. However, after playing a [2d top-down battle royale game](http://surviv.io), it's given me inspiration to build a similar game. The graphics would be very similar, though there would be new things like building.

I'm trying to decide if this concept is different enough; there's another [similar game](https://zombsroyale.io), though it has different graphics and some other key differences.

I'm wondering at what point two games become too similar, and how to avoid taking too many ideas from one game (a common problem for me).

Comment: Are you afraid that you might be violating some copyright? Or that you just want your work to be "unique" ? Are you making the game just to learn or to help your business survive?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking about? "Different enough" for what purpose? "Too similar" by what measure? If you're concerned about legal status & litigation, [we have previous Q&A about that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1653/39518). If you're wondering about market appeal, that's something you'll have to answer though your own market research. We Internet strangers aren't a crystal ball that can predict the future for you.

Comment: I think Redwolf Programs is worried about whether the game is different enough to sell.