# can I legally make a "RTX game"

Tags: legal, copyright

I'm making a game called "karlson RTX", a remake of the game "karlson" by danidev, but it has "RTX" in the name and the game starts with a the way it's meant to be played splash screen, containing the nvidia icon, and soon to be containing it's slogan

[image]

will this game (which will be released free, and open source) run into any  legal issues? and if so how can I fix them?

I suppose it's free advertising for the brand but you can never be too sure, It also isn't in any way offending the brand if anything promoting it

Comment: This looks like a legal question "Am I allowed to use someone else's trademark without permission" (to which the answer is an obvious and emphatic NO), not a question about how to develop the game parts of your game.

Comment: Also related: [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1653/33287). In addition to the legal issues about unlicensed use of Nvidia's trademarks, a clone of a game isn't automatically legal by virtue of being free &/or open source.

Answer (score 3):

NVidia briefly describes trademark usage [here](https://images.nvidia.com/content/includes/gcr/pdf/NVIDIA-Trademark-and-Logo-Usage-Guidelines.pdf) and [here](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/about-us/NVIDIA-Partner-Network-Brand-Guidelines-May-2020.pdf). It sounds like you need to be a partner to use their trademarks, although I think those documents may be primarily directed at hardware manufacturers.

> Partners should not incorporate NVIDIA Brand Features into their own productname, service names, trademarks, logos, or company names.

Perhaps more relevant are their [general legal notices](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/about-nvidia/legal-info/):

> NVIDIA's trademarks may be used publicly with permission only from NVIDIA