# Copyright/trademark protections of character classes

Tags: legal

I want to create a game that uses character classes from World of Warcraft. Are the classes protected by copyright/trademark law? For instance WoW has a Warlock class that is essentially a spell-caster focused in dark magic and summoning demons.

Comment: You may be interested in [How closely can one game legally resemble another?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1653/39518)

Comment: No, that question is different. The only thing that will be used is a single class.

Comment: That's a degree of similarity, and the question above answers "what degree of similarity is a problem?" - you will learn faster if you don't shut out potential insights for not being in the exact form you expected them to be in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the planing and design of your game, I suggest you do a bit of research.

For instance, a simple search for "Warlock" in my favourite search engine leads to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock) which shows that the concept of warlocks dates back to long before WoW was created. Even Heroes of Might and Magic had [Warlocks](https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Warlock_(H1)) in 1995, long before WoW.

Often, game designers will not try to *invent* new terms, they'll use something that exists before that players recognize easily.

IANAL, but it's safe to say that these *terms* are not copyrighted, nor trademarked. Just keep in mind that you should come up with original skills and features; you may get on a more slippery slope if you also intend to "borrow" the skills and features offered in another game.

Comment: Related reading from RGP Stack Exchange: [Are classes from a tabletop RPG copyrightable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/198297/64190)