# When do I need to ask for permission to recreate an old game?

Tags: legal, copyright

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How closely can a game resemble another game without legal problems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems)
>   [Legal issues for a "fangame" of a commercial franchise?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/712/legal-issues-for-a-fangame-of-a-commercial-franchise)

I want to do a mobile version of an old game I used to like called Bow And Arrow ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDcC7oeXym8&feature=related), [game](http://www.undeb.bangor.ac.uk/archery/game.htm)). There's a project already port it in [Ruby](https://github.com/elia/bow_and_arrow). I'm wondering if I can do a remake of this game. Do I have to get permission from the creator, or does it only matter if I use the same resources (graphics and sound)?

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: [Legal issues for a "fangame" of a commercial franchise](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/712/legal-issues-for-a-fangame-of-a-commercial-franchise) and [How closely can a game resemble another game without legal problems](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-resemble-another-game-without-legal-problems)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, and nearly universally around the world: *game systems* (pure mathematical formulas and algorithms) can't be copyrighted, and thus can be copied freely, even without being nice and asking. However, In some jurisdictions they can be protected - in parts or whole - by *patents*.

For everything else, **ask a lawyer**.

Comment: Yep, Tetris for example. The only thing from Tetris you can't use is anything resembling the name Tetris.

Comment: @Gagege Not true. You're also not free to use sound and graphics like Tetris. This [blog](http://desiree47.wordpress.com/) has interesting information about Tetris and legal issues.