# Can I create a Star Wars game without infringing copyright?

Tags: game-industry, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Legal issues for a “fangame” of a commercial franchise?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/712/legal-issues-for-a-fangame-of-a-commercial-franchise)

Is it possible to create my own commercial game based on the Star Wars Universe, without any copyright infringement?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but you can't use Star Wars or any other trademarked names, nor any content from existing games (graphics, sound, etc.) in your game. So, essentially, while possible, it will be a challenge to save the Universe spirit. And anyway, for any such serious attempts (like if your money is involved) you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: Seems like i have to create my own Universe.

Answer (score 2):

It's primarily a trademark issue. You wouldn't be able to do this without trademark infringement (and also, probably copyright infringement).